# How do I keep a website in my webbrowser?

Tags: c#, browser

I'm navigating to a website that forces every page to open in a new webpage. How do I prevent this from happening in my program (I have no control over the website)?

Comment: Is this the WebBrowser control? WinForms, Silverlight? If it is, there are a few ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a WinForms or Silverlight WebBrowser there are a number of options.

You can hijack any navigation events and cancel the navigation then handle it yourself. This could mean just doing your own navigation in-window to the target URL or downloading the page outside of the browser using an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and then inject your own script into the HTML to hijack link clicks and handle them yourself, then have your web browser navigate to the modified HTML string.